# Populate Custom Calendar with json data

Tags: android, json, android-calendar, android-cursor, android-json

I need to get some json data from my server that contains data about the assistence of the company employees. I'm using an example of `CalendarView`

I need to change the data origin from:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, null);
```

to

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("http://www.gettford.net/comunidad/api/calendario.php"),
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, null);
```

Obviously the code is wrong, but i do not know how to put json inside a cursor, i know how to get the json and insert it in an array but in this case i don't know what to do.

Appreciate any help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Obviously the code is wrong`... Why? What seems to be the problem? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved by changing this:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, null);
```

for this:

```
class Asistencia extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            nameOfEvent.clear();
            startDates.clear();
            endDates.clear();
            descriptions.clear();

            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://www.xxx.zzz");
            if (jsonobject != null && jsonobject.length() > 0) {
                try {
                    // Locate the array name in JSON
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("datos");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                        jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Retrive JSON Objects
                        nameOfEvent.add(jsonobject.getString("title"));
                        startDates.add(jsonobject.getString("dtstart"));
                        endDates.add(jsonobject.getString("dtend"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // errores = "conexion";
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

        }

    }
```